# How to add label outside the pie chart

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

How to add values text and slice text outside the chart?

Similar to this image:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Please try this:

```
dataSet.setXValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);
dataSet.setYValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);
```

Those properties put labels outside of chart